# installing laravel dependencies with composer not working

Tags: json, laravel, dependencies, composer-php

I'm trying to install Laravel Excel using [this guide](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/getting-started)

I have included the line in my composer.json;

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "1.*"
},
```

I am then attempting to update composer using the command `composer update`. This results in the following messages....

```
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.

Loading composer repositories with package information

The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "http://packagist.org/p/jeremeamia/functionparser$cac3105ac0ad3f9a0f9c9ccabcde36787c8d8f404a003fa47900f84cee475a34.json" file could not be downloaded: php_

network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

When I try to self-update composer (as recommended in the warning message) I get the following;

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

So my first problem is that I cannot update composer.

My second problem is that I do not think Laravel Excel has been installed because I cannot see it in the vendor/laravel directory anywhere (isn't that where all the dependencies are usually stored?)

I am a complete beginner when it comes to using composer and installing dependencies and I've not really even used a JSON file before until now so really struggling here...

Comment: Better say: are you on local host? Seems something is blocking composer from getting to the site. If it's not your local site, then it may be company firewall.

Comment: The issue is your question misleads reader: really your composer doesn't work at all due to some net problems

Comment: Just run `composer diagnose`to diagnose any problems you or your network have

Comment: @Lambrusco It is on my local host. Using company unrestricted internet though. But I will try again from home later just to be sure.

Comment: @acrobat I get `Checking http connectivity: FAIL` and I think it fails on the `Checking composer version` as well as it leaves that blank

Comment: better try from home. these errors shows that there is some restriction. or proxy. check proxy also, you can do it now

Comment: @Lambrusco I don't really know what a proxy is, how to check it, and what I would be checking for - unless it's a big on/off button that's turned OFF

Comment: then better try installing project again at home and report about your results)

Comment: Can I just manually install LaravelExcel somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same problem. Later, I came to know that my proxy not allowing me to update the composer. So, check your proxy settings.

Comment: Thank you for answering but would you elaborate /give steps for answer . I have now similar issue.

Comment: @ikuchris Go to "Internet properties" and select "Connection" tab. Click on "Lan settings" and uncheck "Use a proxy server for your LAN".

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users (Centos 6,7)
Check your name servers that you have in /etc/resolv.conf working properly with the below command

nslookup www.google.com

If it is not working used the google public name server at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```